# Critical Value of this function

Tags: calculus

So the function is

```
f(x) = 4x3 − 6x2 − 24x
```

I understand how to find critical values so if you could please tell me where i go wrong that would be very helpful.

```
f'(x) = 12(x^2-x-2)
0 = 12(x^2-x-2)
0 = 12(x-2)(x+1)
x - 2 = 0 , x + 1 = 0
x = 2 , x = -1 , x = 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (only) mistake is that $f'(12)=0$. Number $12$ is a constant number. You can actually divide both sides with $12$ to get rid of it and obtain the equation $$0=(x-2)(x+1)$$

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for the quick response